# Something is wrong the alignment of my items in the calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a Calculator using 'Tkinter' and 'python'. Somehow, after creating the mathematical operations, number buttons and the input field, there is something wrong with the alignment of the number buttons, I don't know what! Please help me!
Programming in Jupyter Notebook.
Here is the code which I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

#Creating the input field
inputfield = Entry(root,
                   width = 35,
                   borderwidth = 5)
inputfield.grid(row = 0,
                column = 0,
                columnspan = 3,
                padx = 10,
                pady = 10)


#Defining button function
def button_Add():
    return



#Define buttons
button1 = Button(root, 
                 text = "1",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button2 = Button(root, 
                 text = "2",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button3 = Button(root, 
                 text = "3",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)


button4 = Button(root, 
                 text = "4",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button5 = Button(root, 
                 text = "5",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button6 = Button(root, 
                 text = "6",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)

button7 = Button(root, 
                 text = "7",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button8 = Button(root, 
                 text = "8",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button9 = Button(root, 
                 text = "9",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
button0 = Button(root,
                 text = "0",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)


#Mathematical Operations
#Add
button_Add = Button(root, 
                 text = "+",
                 padx = 10,
                 pady = 10,
                 command = button_Add)
#Subtract
button_Subtract = Button(root,
                         text = "-",
                         padx = 10,
                         pady = 10,
                         command = button_Add)
#Multiply
button_Multiply = Button(root,
                         text = "*",
                         padx = 10,
                         pady = 10,
                         command = button_Add)
#Divide
button_Divide = Button(root,
                       text = "/",
                       padx = 10,
                       pady = 10,
                       command = button_Add)
#Equals to = ?
button_equalto = Button(root, 
                        text = "=",
                        padx = 10,
                        pady = 10,
                        command = button_Add)
#Clear the input
button_clear = Button(root,
                      text = "C",
                      padx = 10,
                      pady = 10,
                      command = button_Add)

#Put the buttons on the screen
button1.grid(row = 3,
             column = 0)
button2.grid(row = 3,
             column = 1)
button3.grid(row = 3,
             column = 2)

button4.grid(row = 2,
             column = 0)
button5.grid(row = 2,
             column = 1)
button6.grid(row = 2,
             column = 2)

button7.grid(row = 1,
             column = 0)
button8.grid(row = 1,
             column = 1)
button9.grid(row = 1,
             column = 2)

button0.grid(row = 4,
             column = 1)

#Mathematical Operations
button_Add.grid(row = 1,
                column = 3)
button_Subtract.grid(row = 2,
                     column = 3)
button_Multiply.grid(row = 3,
                     column = 3)
button_Divide.grid(row = 4,
                   column = 3)
button_clear.grid(row = 1,
                  column = 4)
button_equalto.grid(row = 2,
                    column = 4)

#Running the program
root.mainloop()
```

This is how the output looks:
[Calculator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1v4o.png)
This is how my calculator output looks like when I run it!
I don't want it to look like this!

Comment: Try setting `columnspan=5` for `inputfield`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the buttons are not neatly next to each other is the cause of the input field. It is just simple to solve it: Change the columnspan of the inputfield from 3 to 5, then you see this: [Image calculator solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyDou.png)

```html
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

#Creating the input field
inputfield = Entry(root,
                   width = 35,
                   borderwidth = 5)
inputfield.grid(row = 0,
                column = 0,
                columnspan = 5,
                padx = 10,
                pady = 10)
```

If you want the border of the buttons to be close together, just change the padx and pady of the buttons!